# inotify support not available

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, inotify

Im getting a tailwatch error that I think I have traced down to this from my error logs

```
inotify support not available (Linux::Inotify2 missing or non-functional)
```

Have no idea what this is or how to replace it? Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[inotify](http://inotify.aiken.cz/) is used to monitor file system events.

According to [CPanel's changelog](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/ChangeLog/CPanelVersion1130), you should upgrade to at least version 11.30.0.7:

> Fixed case 48616: Cpanel::TailWatch: inotify support not available